# Reserved keyword in OSX SDK/Carbon, but not on iOS. What to do in a joint iOS/OSX project?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, macos-carbon, reserved-words

I am trying port my iOS application to the Mac OS X SDK, and have found that I am getting the following error message: `'Collection' redeclared as a different kind of symbol.` Is there a possibility that 'Collection.h', which is the name of one of my Core Data entities and is a file in my iOS project, is a reserved name in the OS X SDK?

**UPDATE:** I've dug through the code, and found that the keyword `Collection` is defined within Carbon, in `Collections.h`:

`typedef struct OpaqueCollection*        Collection`

Is there any way to get around this besides changing the name of my Core Data entity?

Answer (score 1):

It's a very common name so it's likely. Cmd+click it to see where it takes you. To avoid collisions you can prefix your classes with a couple of letters, eg: JSCollection for Jason Something.

Comment: Thanks; I've found that it is defined in Carbon (which is why this worked on iOS but is causing problems on OSX). Any suggestions besides just changing the name of my entity?

Comment: @Jason: are you sure you need to use Carbon in your MacOSX project? if not, I think you should be able to get rid of it completely, including Collections.h...

Comment: How do I get rid of Carbon from my project? I am making a Cocoa project so I don't need the older compatibility layers.

Comment: You don't get rid of it. Cocoa still needs them.

Answer (score 1):

the compiler should also tell you where that symbol was originally defined, so you can easily check...

Comment: Thanks - I've looked this up and found that it's in Carbon (I've put the information as an update to the question).